# Consumer Selection in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a system that sends messages via RabbitMQ.  The messages contain an Order ID.

The receiving system looks in its database to see if the Order ID exists.  If it does not, then it inserts it.  If it does, then it updates it.  It looks like this:

```
var doesOrderIdExistInDb = context.CheckIfOrderIdExists(order.OrderId);

if (doesOrderIdExistInDb)
{
    UpdateOrder(order);
} else 
{
    InsertOrder(order);
}
```

The problem I have is that I can have several messages in a row for a single Order ID.

When those messages are split between consumers, they all execute the above checks and code at the same time.  Meaning they all check to see if the Order ID exists (it does not), then they all try to insert the order (all but one fail).

I need some way to get all messages for an Order ID to go to a single consumer.

This would be easy if there were some way to select the consumer.  (I could do a modulo operation on the Order ID using the number of workers.  Since the Order ID is sequential, it would distribute normally among the consumers.)

What I would like to avoid is having to make a new queue to send to per consumer.  My consumers should be elastic (growing in number as my load grows).

**Is there a way to get all my Order IDs to go to the same consumer?** (besides making a new queue for each consumer.)

Answer (score 0):

Messages in a queue are consumed by the next available consumer. The RabbitMQ server can not decide to *not* deliver the next message to the next available consumer in a way you have in mind.

**But** the consumers can decide which messages routed to them they accept and which they reject.

**Additional data** to make this work:

- Each consumer would have to keep a record of which orders he is interested in.
- The first message for an oder must have a property that identifies it as the first message.

If a message is routed to a consumer, he follows these steps:

- If the **message is the first for an order**, the consumer **accepts** it. It records the fact that it is working on this order.
- Else,

  - if the consumer has recorded that it is working on the order the message belongs to, he **accepts** the message,
  - else, he **rejects** it. The message will be requeued.

This will guarantee that once a consumer has started to work on the first message of an order, no other consumer will work on messages that belong to this order.